# Merging Pandas DF with a Geopandas Shapefile removes all the rows except column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas

I am trying to merge a pandas DataFrame `df` with a GeoPandas shapefile `gdf`.
Whenever I try to merge the two together, the output for `gdf.head()` only shows the column names and no rows of data under it.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/sds cw/cars.csv')
shape = gpd.read_file('~/Desktop/sds cw/Europe_SWAsia.shp')
shape.rename(columns = {'NAME' : 'Country'}, inplace = True)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df.merge(shape, on = 'Country'))
gdf.head()
```

The output is:

[image]

I have merged Pandas with shapefiles before and this has never happened so I am a bit confused as to why. Maybe it has something to do with the actual .csv?

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After replacing the shapefile with a different one, the problem no longer persists. However, still an interesting question, so feel free to answer.

Comment: if the contents of *Country* are not consistent across the **pandas** dataframe and **geopandas** geodataframe it's exactly the result you expect....

Comment: both had consistent names of each country, and were merged on the correct column name